# cart and checkout doesn't work in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress

I include woocommerce/template in my theme with this name : 'woocommerce' and also use add_theme_support() in my functions.php to introduce it .
but when user add a product to cart and wants to see the cart , user redirect to index.php
what should I do to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I fix it. it was so stupid.
I just forgot to add page.php in my theme

```
<?php get_header(); if (have_posts()) {while (have_posts({the_content();}}get_footer();
```

because cart shortcut need to display in a page .

Answer (score 0):

@Ali Please share your code so I can have better idea.

OR

1. Add Theme Support Code to functions.php file

   function mytheme_add_woocommerce_support() {
       add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
   }
   add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_add_woocommerce_support' );
2. Created folder "woocommerce" into your theme folder.
3. Copy all files from "wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/" to this folder.
4. Add below code to functions.php file.

   function my_custom_add_to_cart_redirect( $url ) {
      $url = get_permalink( get_option( 'woocommerce_checkout_page_id' ) ); 
      return $url;
   } 
   add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'my_custom_add_to_cart_redirect' );

Try this.

Comment: Thanks , for answering, exactly I do this steps but still have have the problem....... there is no to much code I just start to learn woocommerce, its just index.php, style.css , functions.php and woocommerce directory

Comment: @AliNorouzi try this code and let me know if you need any other help in this. Thank you.

Comment: here is my functions.php   ---- function mytheme_add_woocommerce_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_add_woocommerce_support' );

Comment: I got this error ::: Notice: WC_Cart::get_cart_url is deprecated since version 2.5! Use wc_get_cart_url instead. in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-includes\functions.php on line 4435

Comment: @AliNorouzi Also you can do admin side, go to WooCommerce > Settings > Products > Display and enable option: “Redirect to the cart page after successful addition”

Comment: still have the problem :(